# What are objections on Sabda Brahman school thought?

Tags: brahman, brahma-sutras

One of the oldest schools of Vedanta which existed long before Shankara is Sabda- Brahma vivarta vada.

The exponents of this school of thought as stated by Swami Vedanta Desika ( famous SriVaishnava acharya belonging to 13 th century) are Bhartrihari and Halayudha who belonged to school of grammarians.Though they are primarily grammarians and have contributed scholarly works including a commentary on Patanjali Mahabhasya ( commentary on Panini sutras), they too have attempted to give a vedantic complexion to their theories by conceiving Sabda or sound as Brahman, the Ultimate reality of Upanishads.

Bhartrhari : Sabda Brahman is the only ultimate reality and all the world is vivarta (illusory) manifestation of it.

Halayudha : Sabda Brahman alone is the life energy of all entities in the universe and the entire universe is the modification ( Parinama) of it.

Swami Desikan quotes the central doctrine of Halayudha as follows

Sabda Brahma yadekam yac-chaitanyam ca sarvabhutanam !

Yat Parinamam tribhuvanam Akhilam idam jayanthi as Vani !!

Meaning : Sabda Brahma, the one reality without a second, is the life energy of all beings and the entire universe is a modification of it.

Swami Desikan refutes these theories as untenable in his famous works

My questions are

(1) What does Brahma sutras of Badarayana say about this Sabda Brahman school of thought?

(2) Do any of the acharyas viz Ramanuja, Shankara or Madhva say anything about this school of thought?

(3) What are the objections raised and refutations by Swami Desikan against Sabda Brahman school of thought?

Please quote from valid references and valid commentaries, accordingly.

Comment: Interesting, in what work does Vedanta Desikan discuss Bhatrihari and Halayudha?  I've vaguely heard of Bhartihari as an early Vedantic thinker who had much in common with Kashmiri Shaivites like Abhinavagupta, who also believe in Sabda Brahman.  I haven't heard of Halayudha though.

Comment: @@Keshav - In Paramathabhanga and Tattva Mukta kalapa, Swami Desikan discuses and refutes the Sabda Brahman school of thought.